# Personalize Google Search to show certain sites based on keyword or term trigger

Tags: google-search

Can I set some sort of preference to say, when `df` is typed, set the first result to be `bay12games...` on my computer alone and not for the entire web?

Say I want to type this in Google Search:

> df

I want this to be the first answer that only my computer will return:

> [image: custom search result from Google]

Not this actual listing:

> [image: actual search results]

I'm not asking about getting my website to rank or show up first in the results, but rather customising what is shown to me and me alone.

Comment: Kindly explain your question as to why you want to do so? Is my answer correct?

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why do you want this? (I’m not trying to be judgmental here, I’m just curious.)

Comment: I doubt you could be able to do this natively. Maybe it could be possible through some Greasemonkey script, by building a set of keyword(s)/site pairs that you can update on a per case basis.

Comment: Out of pure curiosity, why do you want this? (I’m not trying to be judgmental here, I’m also just curious.)

Comment: @myselfpoddar The games/sites I like to go on are not the most well known sites in the world, and I hate typing in bay12 df or Dwarf Fortress every single time or having to scroll down 5 search terms. I know that its only .5 seconds more, but it bugs me when I have to do the scrolling. :)

Comment: @Russell Why don't you just Bookmark the df page on bay12games?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google does have a personalized search, providing you are logged in to your Google account and you have Google Web History enabled. This will customise the search results for your machine/account only.

However, I don't think you can be so specific as to control the exact position of these results and to position a particular site at the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

> The games/sites I like to go on are not the most well known sites in
>   the world, and I hate typing in bay12 df or Dwarf Fortress every
>   single time or having to scroll down 5 search terms. I know that its
>   only .5 seconds more, but it bugs me when I have to do the scrolling.

This has nothing to do with Google search, but... A service such as [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) (free) allows you to set up shortcuts on your network, whereby you could type "df" into the *address bar* of your browser and you would be taken directly to a website of your choice.

If you change the Primary/Secondary DNS in your router, then this will work on all browsers on all machines on your network.

Comment: Just be aware that there are some disadvantages (ie: related to CDNs) when using services like OpenDNS.